# app failing on buttonClick()

Tags: android, multithreading, buttonclick

here's the app code ,the mainactivity() consists of a buttonClick() onClick() event that is registered in the layout's xml() file! , nothing happens if the button is clicked and there is nothing in run() but as soon as I put something is run() and click the button the app dies?

I'm trying to have Thread!

```
public void buttonClick(View view)
    {

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {         
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hehe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    chikki();
                }
          };
    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();
    }
```

link to logcat >> http://winacro.com/AndroidLOGCAT/crasher.txt

Here's the activity code:

```
package com.example.elecimp;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // JSON Node names
    private static EditText jsonView;
    private static Button but1;
    private static Thread th;
    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;
    private String strJSONValue = "{\"information\":[ {\"sub1_attr\":\"sub1_attr_value\" },{\"sub1_attr\":\"sub2_attr_value\" }]}}}";
    private JSONObject jsonObject;

    String strParsedValue = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        jsonView = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        }

    public void buttonClick(View view)
    {

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {         
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hehe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    chikki();
                }
          };
    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();
    }

   public void chikki() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hehe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   public void parseJSON() {
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
            String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
            String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
            String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            //contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: can you post logcat output?

Comment: An `onClick` event should be in your layout, not manifest file. That's probably why the button is unresponsive.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong actually its in the layout file.xml only

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something with UI(eg- Showing a Toast) in the thread? If yes, then your your app will not work. If you want to do something UI related you'll have to use

runonuithread

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

OR

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**Edit**

You need to change this

```
public void buttonClick(View view)
{

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {         
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hehe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                chikki();
            }
      };
    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
    mythread.start();
}
```

to this

```
public void buttonClick(View view)
{
  Thread mythread  = new Thread("Thread1") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    chikki();
                }
            });

        }
    };
    mythread .start();
}
```

Comment: i made a new thread you mean even that new thread is on the same UI thread so thread on thread is happen to run?

Comment: A new Thread by definition can't be "on the same UI thread". It doesn't matter where you instantiated the new thread, it's a new Object and therefor not the same Object as the UI Thread, (which the OS creates for you). You can't touch UI stuff from anything other than the UI thread.

Comment: I have added the MyActivity code: above please! lookonto it and tell me the problem , Please